# MVC3 HandleError

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I went through all the posts with similar problem before posting this.

I want MVC to display the view for my unhandled errors in the code but instead when i debug it keeps on stopping at the line below that throws the exception.

1) App's root web.config has the following:

```
<customErrors mode="On"></customErrors>
```

2) Controller Action Method:

```
[HandleError()]
        public ActionResult ShowErrorHandle()
        {
            int a = 10, b = 0; 
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
            return Content(a.ToString(),"text/plain",Encoding.Default);
        }
```

I also tried to replace the default HandleError above with something more specific but it is still the same issue:

```
[HandleError(ExceptionType=typeof(Exception), View="AnotherIndex")]
```

I stripped out error.cshtml file entirely except 1 line and made sure it was working.

LOki.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know -- when debugging, you'll always hit the line of exceptions because Exception breakpoints are turned on by default in VS.

You can try to edit the settings in Debug --> Exceptions (Ctrl + D, E)